# Rails - Add a route prefix to a specific directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a messy rails 3 application that's come from a different developer and I need to refactor it.

What I want to do is move the contents of "app" into a subfolder called "classic".

```
app/classic
```

And then have all URL's with a classic prefix such as

```
localhost:3000/classic/wills/new
```

Route to controllers inside of the "app/classic" folder.

And then every regular url that does not contain the classic prefix - route in the standard way to app/

Is it possible to do this? The only thing I've discovered so far is that I can add a scope inside of my routes file.

```
scope(:path => '/classic')
```

But all that does is require a prefix for every URL. I'm really not sure how to go about this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a route namespace.  Take a look at this section in Rails Routing from the Outside In:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

```
namespace :classic do
  # your routes here
end
```

This will do 3 things -

- the path to the controller files need to be under /app/controllers/classic/
- the name of the controllers need to change to Classic::ControllerName
- the url is now /classic/controller/action

This sounds like what you want, but you can modify this to get just the parts you want if you don't want all 3.

Comment: That's almost what I'm looking for thanks. But I want to be able to add everything inside of the "classic" directory. So controllers would go inside of "app/classic/controllers/"

Comment: But it turns out that it's not possible to do this in Rails, thanks for your solution, I will go with this :)

Answer (score 1):

**In route.rb file:**

```
#Of course, you have to configure the right http method.

get 'wills/new' => 'wills#new', as: 'to_classic_wills_new'
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: I completely forgot you could write it as `get 'wills/new' => 'wills#new'`!, I've always done this way: `get 'wills/new', to: 'wills#new'`.